# PINN no internet connection after hard reset

Tags: networking, pi-3b+, noobs, dhcp, fedora

I have recently installed and configured a new server on my raspberry pi 3B. I used [PINN](https://github.com/procount/pinn/blob/master/README_PINN.md) as my bootloader and installed some OSes (Fedberry - an Raspberry Fedora implementation - being the main one). I have configured everything on the bootloader an Fedora itself that I wanted to work.

The pi os working solely as server without display or any other peripherals. I'm connecting to it over SSH or VNC to do some configuring.

Lastly I had to unplug my Raspberry for few hours. After plugging it in again there was no network connection to it (neither ping, ssh nor vnc). I didn't tried looking into it with display for troubleshooting, instead I restarted my router (Fritz Box 7360) and could connect to my Raspberry as everytime before again.

After that my guess was, that it would be something about DHCP configuration on my Raspberry but it seems fine. I tested some configurations like nmcli (Network Manager CLI) and could confirm that services like DHCP are actually working.

I can't find any reason why the raspberry that normally connects to the wired network can't repeat the process after being unplugged and plugged back in. When I reboot through the Fedberry CLI via sudo reboot I have no problems whit connectivity.

I would be glad about some directions about where to look for a solution to the problem. The Firtz Box restart workaround works but it removes the connectivity to the internet to other devices for the reboot time. Besides I imagine there is some solution to this problem that I'm simply missing.

Thanks in Advance.

Edit: When I talk about unplugging it's not about ethernet cable but the power cable to shut down the device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you unplugged the wired ethernet cable from the RasPi for some hours. When plugged in again the network connection isn't reestablished.

I don't know how exactly your setup looks so I can only guess a possible reason. It may be that the DHCP client on the RasPi does not recognize that the connection is broken but the Fritz!BOX do. So it will cut the connection. If you reboot the Fritz!BOX it recognizes that the RasPi is back again and connect to it.

Check if the RasPi will reconnect when the given lease time of the ip address has expired. Then it will RENEW its lease and maybe reconnect.

Comment: I talked about unplugging the power cable not the ethernet cable. Nevertheless the problem might be the same. When I unplug the power cable the pi might not have time to free up the dhcp lease, and when back up again the router just can't giveaway the same ip address.

Comment: @patvax You mean to unplug the power cable, you don't talked about it ;-)

Comment: Yeah I currently just set a static IP and it works just fine. I have no idea why the dhcp client can't get the IP address during boot. The Router should even respond with the same IP the raspberry had recently.